# Get a list of Relaying Party Trust Identifiers from ADFS using C#?

Tags: c#, adfs

Does anyone know of a way to pull the list of all Relaying Party Trust Identifiers from ADFS using C#?  I know I can do it with Powershell, but would rather not have an xml file I then have to move and import into my C# program.

Comment: You could always run the PowerShell from C# - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: Yes, looking at doing this now-- hitting a stumbling point with my reference for 'System.Management.Automation.' I seem to be missing a .dll the reference needs to actually work.  You will think I'm crazy, but I'm not using Visual Studio for this and am just coding by hand.  I didn't want to install it just for this one project because usually I'm just coding in PHP, if coding at all. Everything I'm reading on MSDN says that VS will give me the dll as soon as I add the reference to the web.config file (already have the SDK), so I may have to cave and install it anyway. Bleh. Over-complication.